# newbie to nested if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I am learning to use Java and code on my own, I am network Tech and wanted to learn how to Code.  I am learning from a site called programming by doing and I am stuck on one assignment:

https://programmingbydoing.com/a/twenty-questions.html

below is my code, it will compile but the issue is with the nested if statement not working properly please help!!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class twentyQuestions 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String question1, question2, guess;

        System.out.println("TWO QUESTIONS!");
        System.out.println("Think of an object, and I will try to guess it.");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Question 1: Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral?");
        question1 = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Question 2: Is it bigger than a bread box?");
        question2 = keyboard.next();


        if (question1.equals("animal"))

        {
                if (question2.equals("no"))

                {
                    guess = "squirrel";
                }
                else {
                    guess = "moose";
                }
        }


        else if (question1.equals("vegetable"))

            {
            if (question2.equals("no"))
            {
                guess = "carrot";
            }
            else 
            {
                guess = "watermelon";
            }
            }


        else if (question1.equals("mineral"));


        {
            if (question2.equals("no"))
            {
                guess = "paper clip";
            }
            else 
            {
                guess = "Camaro";
            }

        }

        System.out.println("You're thinking of a " + guess);
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: `nested if statement not working properly` how so? You have more than one nested if statement

Comment: the code complies with no errors... it is when you enter "animal" or Vegetable you dont get the out come that is listed under them

Comment: start code formatting at import statement

Comment: Remove that semicolon following that last `else if`.

Comment: lol oh the trusty old semicolons after if statements. Nice catch @rgettman

Comment: First i am not sure what you mean by code formatting mean... but i do understand to start at the import statement......

Comment: 2nd i removed the ";"  and got this error:   c:\CompSci>javac twentyQuestions.java

c:\CompSci>javac twentyQuestions.java
twentyQuestions.java:66: error: variable guess might not have been initialized
        System.out.println("You're thinking of a " + guess);
                                                     ^
1 error

Comment: Then initialize `guess`... Use the compile errors to fix problems by yourself, and your life shall be easier.

Comment: WOW Thank you all!!!!!! that worked..... for someone like me to know nothing about JAVA and all your Help!!! thanks a million

Comment: @austinwernli can u tell me about compiler errors i am using notepad++ and then running it in Command line

Comment: Your compile error states `error: variable guess might not have been initialized`. So you simply fix the problem by initializing the variable. Why not use Eclipse IDE or something similar?

Comment: okay will have to download it thank a million @austinwernli

Comment: in the end before the final println add `else { guess = "thing that is neither an animal, vegetable or mineral."; }`. That's the case in which you don't assign a value to `guess`.

Answer (score 1):

First off all, you need to remove the semicolon after

```
else if (question1.equals("mineral"))
```

Then, you need to add a final `else` block at the end of the `if` statement to catch input that does not match any of the three inputs. Then it will be able to compile:

```
    ...
    else if (question1.equals("mineral"))

    {
        if (question2.equals("no")) {
            guess = "paper clip";
        } else {
            guess = "Camaro";
        }

    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: it should be able to compile without final else.

Comment: No it will not, because the variable guess will not be initialized in the case that the input doesn't match any of the cases - even if you know that the input will always be correct, the compiler will not allow it

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been downvoted but, let me give you a hand here, +1 as your answer does address the issue and provide a fix

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU ALL here is my final code that works thanks to everyone...:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twentyQuestions 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String question1, question2, guess = "";

```
    System.out.println("TWO QUESTIONS!");
    System.out.println("Think of an object, and I will try to guess it.");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Question 1: Is it an animal, vegetable, or mineral?");
    question1 = keyboard.next();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Question 2: Is it bigger than a bread box?");
    question2 = keyboard.next();


    if (question1.equals("animal"))

    {
            if (question2.equals("no"))

            {
                guess = "squirrel";
            }
            else {
                guess = "moose";
            }
    }


    else if (question1.equals("vegetable"))

        {
        if (question2.equals("no"))
        {
            guess = "carrot";
        }
        else 
        {
            guess = "watermelon";
        }
        }


    else if (question1.equals("mineral"))


    {
        if (question2.equals("no"))
        {
            guess = "paper clip";
        }
        else 
        {
            guess = "Camaro";
        }

    }

      else{
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    return;
    }

    System.out.println("You're thinking of a " + guess);
    }

}
```